# if ... in - no match when it has to be

Tags: python, if-statement, match

I have a database of words and a dataset with text lines. Every time there is a word in the line of the text file that appears in the words file as well, I want to do a trick. My code looks like:

```
import re
f = open(r"words.txt")
print len(flist)
d = open(r"text.txt", "r")
dlist = d.readlines()

for line in flist:
    lowline = line.lower()
    for word in dlist:
        lowword = word.lower()
        if lowword in lowline:
            *trick*
```

However, this code finds no matches, altough there are many words that are exactly the same. Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Have you mixed up your files and variables? The `word` variable appears to be read from the `text.txt` file, whereas `line` is from `words.txt`, which seems to suggest that you need to swap them around.

Comment: readlines returns the lines with a newline at the end of the string. you're not going to find `'cat\n'` inside `'my cat is black\n'`

Comment: @andersschuller Sorry, I messed it up in this post because I wanted to simplify the file names.

Comment: @jterrace Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the words from database into a `set` first and apply `str.strip` and `str.lower` to them. `str.strip` will remove the leading and trailing white space characters like `'\n'`,etc.

Sets provide `O(1)` lookup, and also set intersections is going to be much more efficient than your current `O(n^2)` approach.

Then iterate over each line in words file and apply `str.strip` and `str.lower` first before searching for it in the set.

```
with open(r"words.txt") as f1, open(r"text.txt", "r") as f2:

    dlist = set(line.strip().lower() for line in f2)  #set of words from database
    for line in f1:
        line = line.strip().lower()     #use strip to remove '\n'
        words = set(line.split())    #use split to get the words from the line
                                     #and convert it into a set
        common_words = words & dlist  #use set intersection to find common words
        for word in common_words:  
           *trick*
```

Please replace `f1` and `f2` appropriately as I am confused which one is database and which one is text dataset.